# Deployment of External Configuration Files

Tags: .net, deployment, continuous-integration, teamcity, automated-deploy

We currently use external configuration files to manage certain configurations in our ASP.Net MVC applications.  Some examples are appsettings, connectionStrings, and logging configurations.

I am familiar with using transformations to change the Web.Config across different build configurations, but there doesn't seem to be a facility to do these transformations when using external configuration files.

I'm also concerned that creating separate build configurations for each environment might not be using the feature as intended--is a build configuration (which by default includes Debug and Release) intended to represent a deployment environment (Dev, QA, Staging, Production)?

We are using TeamCity, although I'd imagine this question would apply to any build server.

Is there a built-in or recommended way to manage external/referenced configuration files that change per deployment environment?  Is this something that should be managed at the solution level, or is it more a function of the build server?

Answer (score 0):

The selection of right configuration setting is part of the deployment process. Any decent deployment tool provides the required tools to select and apply the correct configuration to your deployment. for example this is how [Octopus handles it](http://octopusdeploy.com/documentation/features/xml-config).

However if you don't use a dedicated Deployment engine, you can code your own script to handle your need. All you have to do is to put markers in your configuration files and define dictionaries for each environment and use a script to decide what dictionary will be applied to the template in deployment process.

I have found [this implementation](http://configgen.codeplex.com/)  that uses excel files to keep the values. IMHO its overkill and excel files are not very diff friendly. An INI file should be more than enough in most cases.